# Referencing specific folder as subrepository

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I want to import specific folder from external repository. I can surely import whole repository as subrepository but i don't want to bring whole project so i only need a specific folder.

Is this possible to do via Mercurial ?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

No, you can see and use the whole  Mercurial repository only, not it's subtree

**Longer answer**

You can convert any part of repository-tree into separate repository and use this thin repo (problem of syncing trimmed repo with upstream will be anyway your headache)